# Is it possible to change a cluster that is dependent on a domain?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, cluster

Recently we received (2) Poweredge 6850 and (2) PowerVault 220s from our managed server company. These two servers hosted SQL Server 2005 with our SQL database on it. The cluster was dependent on their domain. I did not have any of their passwords, and they were not sharing them, so I cleared the local administrator's password and logged onto the server. I see all the different drive names, but none of them are showing how much space they have. I am assuming because the cluster service is failing to load. I changed the services' accounts to the local system so they can run, but it is still failing to load.

Should I be able to see the drives without the servers clustered together? Am I going to have to re-cluster the servers? If I do, will I lose all the information?

Answer (score 0):

A windows cluster can not start with access to the AD domain it was created in.

You're cluster is SOL without that domain.

You should be able to access the MDB and LDF files on the PowerVaults however, create new SQL services and attach the database(s). This is not a light undertaking by any means however.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that taking a SQL Server cluster from one domain to another is possible (if messy) - except that the shared storage for a clustered instance of SQL Server had to be SAN attached, and hence must still reside with your managed services company. The local storage that comes with the two physical nodes (ie servers) wouldn't contain the data for a clustered SQL Server instance.

It's possible that the SQL Server instance was not clustered, and hence the data would be on the local drives - but what would be the point of that...? I'm guessing that the only drive is the C: drive that you can see space for, or possibly even C: was SAN attached too.

Hopefully you've got backups.....